# Correct English Grammar

Tags: grammar, american-english

Based on this message:

> I hope you consider my application has awaken your interest and I
>   am looking forward for a meeting with you to explain deeply of myself.

The message is used in the end of my resume. Do you consider the message as correct grammar?

Today, I'm a newbie in English Language & usage.

Comment: This looks like proof-reading.

Answer (score 1):

The only things that are actually 'incorrect', are that 'awaken', should read 'awoken'( the past participle); and 'for a meeting' should be 'to a meeting'.

However even with those corrections the message is still a little quaintly expressed, in the words of a non-native speaker. I don't think, for example I would use the verb 'awoken', as it slightly suggests the reader may have been half asleep! I would also take out the 'consider' as it is not really necessary. Moreover I would not offer to 'explain' myself to a potential interviewer, as the word carries the unfortunate nuance that one is complicated and needs explanation.  If you wish to appear as a native speaker, and to create a good impression, I would write.

'I hope my application has interested you, and I look forward to a meeting in which I can describe myself more fully.'

Comment: Yes, only sea-monsters get awoken these days.

Comment: The verb is _awaken_, not _awake_, so the participle should be _awakened_. “I hope I have awoken your interest” definitely does not sound right to me, whereas “I hope I have awakened your interest” sounds merely quaint.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Both 'awakened' and 'awoken' are quoted as past participles of 'awake', in the Oxford Dictionary of English. 'Awoken' sounds more natural to me as a native speaker. 'They were awoken by the sound of gunfire.' But I am a bit old fashioned, and was not born to the metropolitan class, so don't take what I say as gospel.

Comment: But this is _awaken_, not _awake_ (or was that a typo?). It sounds very odd to my ear: I would say “I have awoken”, but “I was awakened”—but the difference may be simply idiolectal.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm finding this quite interesting. Please could you give me an example of how you would use 'awoken'.

Comment: “I had awoken early, but I lazed in bed for a long time, so it was quite late when I arrived at work.”