# A study of awake and awaken

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, wake-waken-awake-awaken

It has been drawn to my attention that I may not be using the verb 'awake'correctly in the active and passive. Please could someone confirm that I have now got this right.

In their simple present tenses they are: Active, 'I awake each morning at 6.00am'; and passive, 'I am awaken each morning by an alarm clock'.

Past tenses therefore are: Active, 'I awoke this morning at 5.00am'; and Passive, 'I was awaken by the sound of thunder'.

Perfect: Active, 'I have awoken early all my life'; and passive, 'I have often been awakened by a passing train'

Pluperfect: Active,'I had awoken by the time the phone rang'; and passive, ' I had been awakened by noises downstairs'.

Which other verbs behave in this way?

Comment: There are ***two*** different verbs here, *awake* and *awaken*. You are using one in the active and the other in the passive. Why does English have two different verbs which mean essentially the same thing? Probably for the same reason it has *lie* and *lay*: the two verbs diverged in pronunciation historically, and acquired different uses. With *awake* and *awaken*, the two different uses may be unique to you (although I'd guess most likely not).

Comment: I have never heard someone say they "awake each morning". It may be correct, but it sounds awkward. Generally, it's "wake-up".

Comment: _I am **awakened** each morning . . ._ is a form I have never seen.  I thought the past participle of **awaken** was **awakened**.

Comment: @Babs, it is. Is there a typo in your comment? You appear to be saying that you have never seen the form that you thought to be the correct form (?).

Comment: @Janus. Darn.  It's a typo.  Lost my credibility on that one. I have never seen _I am **awaken**._

Comment: @Peter Shor  So what is the passive of 'awake', and the active of 'awaken'? I suppose the former has no passive, and the latter could be 'My grandson awakens the dead when he plays his drums'. Is that right? Lie and lay are quite different. One is about being horizontal, the other about eggs.

Comment: The passive for *"awake"* is *"I am awoken"*. The passive for *"awaken"* is *"I am awakened"*. But since that "*ed*" is barely pronounced, *"I am awaken"* sounds nearly the same, and I assume you learned these verbs in spoken form. So I guess the question is: are there other people who use *"awake"* only in the active voice and *"awaken"* only in the passive voice.

Comment: Of course it has a passive.  _I was **awoken** by the nurse.

Comment: @Peter Shor I've read your comment again, and think you may be saying that one can interchange 'awake' and 'awaken'. So one can say 'I awaken each day at 7.00am'. All this started when Janus BJ objected to my saying 'I was awoken' maintaining it should be 'I was awakened'. I also now see your point about lie/lay.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you reading these comments? Others are now saying that 'I was awoken' is perfectly possible.

Comment: For *lie/lay*, it looks like they were different verbs back in proto-Germanic, but they were *leugan* and *lagjanan*, so as a wild guess, I would bet they're etymologically related.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+awakened%2C+I+was+awoken&year_start=1800&year_end=2007&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20awakened%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20awoken%3B%2Cc0) shows that *"I was awoken"* is used, but rare, and much rarer in AmE than in BrE.

Comment: @Peter, they are certainly related. ‘Lay’ is a bog-standard Germanic causative (with the causative suffix _*-ja-_) to ‘lie’. Unfortunately, ‘lie’ in itself forms its regular present with a different, but identical, suffix _*-ja-_ used to form presents—so the two end up looking quite similar. If you go further back, to PIE, they are more regular: both are from the root _*legʰ-_, and ‘lie’ is from _*légʰ-i̯e-ti_ (‘he lies’, with a normal _*-i̯e-_ present), whereas ‘lay’ is from _*logʰ-éi̯e-ti_ (‘he lays’, a typical causative with root o-grade and the causative suffix _*-ei̯e-_).

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps because I began life with a strong regional dialect's influence my inclination is to say 'I was awoken by the telephone'. My Chinese wife, who has spoken English as a first language since age 5, and whose standard constructions are more reliable than mine, inclines to 'I was awakened by the telephone'.

Comment: That passive *"I am awaken each morning"* doesn't sound at all good to me. I probably wouldn't use the ***a-*** prefixed version anyway, but if I did, it would be either *"I am **awoken** each morning"* or more likely *"I am **awakened** each morning"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We have now come full circle for it was JBJ's suggestion that 'I am awoken' was incorrect which began this. My OP here was based on my acceptance of that view. But he has now accepted 'I am awoken' and I was awoken', though he finds the latter 'a bit off'.

Comment: @WS2: Janus is wise in the ways of words, as I'm sure we all agree. But sometimes a bit too prescriptivist for me. I think if people know what you mean, and only few of them think your usage is ignorant/incorrect, whatever form you use is okay. But you can't really go wrong with *I am/was awakened*, so if you're worried about being called out, just stick with that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers He doesn't know what 'D'yar fa ki a dikker, bor' means, and I doubt you do either!

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91114
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/171832 
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/221905

Answer (score 5):

This is part of quite a complex group of verbs that are, and have been throughout the history of the English language, frequently (con)fused in various ways.

The OED’s entrance on [*awake*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13864) has a very thorough etymological description, which I quote here with some edits (removing extraneous details that obscure more than they clarify and highlighting a few things):

> In this, as in the simple *wake*, two early verbs are mixed up; the form-history being complicated with that of *awaken*, as the sense-history is with that of *awecche* (q.v.).
>
> For the **intransitive verb**, Old English has *awæcnan, awōc, awacen*, compound of *wæcnan, wōc, wacen*, the present stem having a formative *-n-*: *wak-n-*. This present began already in Old English to be treated as a weak verb, with past tense *awæcnede*; whence modern English *awaken, awakened*. Late Old English had also a weak verb *awacian, awacode*, in form a compound of *wacian, wacode* ‘to watch, keep awake’, but in sense identical with *awæcnan*, and perhaps originating in a confusion of the two. This gave Middle and modern English *awake, awaked*.
>
> After the weak form *awakened* came into common use (as past tense of *awaken*), the original relation of *awoke* and its past participle to that verb became obscured; and later instinct, in accordance with the general analogies of the language, has referred them to *awake*, treating them as strong equivalents of *awaked*.
>
> Of all these forms the sense was in Old English only intransitive ‘to arise or come out of sleep,’ the **transitive (causal) sense** of ‘rouse from sleep’ being expressed by the derivative *awęcc(e)an*, Middle English *awecche* (cf. German *erwecken*); but soon after 1100, *awake* began to be used in this sense also, and at length superseded *awecche*, which is not found after 1300.
>
> **There has been some tendency, especially in later times, to restrict the strong past tense (*awoke*) and past participle (*awaken*) to the original intransitive sense; and the weak inflection (*awakened*) to the transitive sense, but this has never been fully carried out.**
>
> The strong past participle *awaken* was already in 13th cent. reduced to *awake*, and at length became merely an adjective (mostly predicative), after which a new form from the past tense, *awoken* was substituted; but the weak form *awaked* is also in common use. (Shakespeare used only the weak inflections.)

Add to this what they have to say about [*awaken*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13867):

> Old English *awæcnan* ‘to waken’. In Old English *awæcnan* was a strong verb with past tense and participle *awōc*, *awacen*. But sometimes the present stem (being irregular) was mistaken for a weak verb, whence already in 9th cent. the past *awæcnede*, modern *awakened*, which is now treated as the proper past tense, while *awoke* and its accompanying past participle are referred to the originally weak *awake*. Like *awake*, this was also at first strictly intransitive; **the transitive use is of comparatively recent appearance, but now the most frequent**.

– and we get a very muddled picture indeed. Especially when there is also the uncompounded verbs *wake* and *waken* to consider (they’re as convoluted).

My ***personal*** feeling, which corresponds quite well with the OED’s examples and description, is that both *awake* and *awaken* have the possibility to be used both transitively and intransitively, but that by far the most common usage is that ***awake* is intransitive** while ***awaken* is transitive**.

Moreover, ***awake* is strong (*awake, awoke, have awoken*)** while ***awaken* is weak (*awaken, awakened, have awakened*)**.

In other words, I would say, intransitively:

> I awake at six o’clock every morning.
> I awoke at six o’clock yesterday morning.
> I had already awoken when the alarm went off at six o’clock this morning.

– but transitively:

> I awaken him at six o’clock every morning.
> I awakened him at six o’clock yesterday morning.
> I had already awakened him when the alarm went off at six o’clock this morning.

(However I say it, of course, it’s a big fat lie—there’s no way I’m awake at six in the morning. But that’s incidental.)

The opposite usages are historically well-founded, but (as mentioned in the highlighted paragraph in the etymology above) there has been a tendency to move away from them over recent centuries, and they often sound downright jarring to me, though not always. For example, “I awake him at six every morning” sounds quite ungrammatical to my ear, whereas “I was awoken at six this morning” sounds only somewhat ‘off’, and the Enya song *I May Not Awaken* sounds perfectly fine. (This is where the [comments on the question that spurred this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148630/correct-english-grammar/148637?noredirect=1#comment307291_148637) become relevant: the usage there is transitive, as in “I awake him at six every morning”, and sounds downright ungrammatical to my ear.)

Of course, in actual, practical usage, I’m much more likely to use *wake up* (which is indifferent to transitivity) in both cases; but that’s irrelevant to the discussion about these particular verbs.

Comment: I was going to give the etymology with mine, but gave up, they were so entangled and originally separated by less that 100 years.

Comment: @Susan, that’s why you got your answer in quicker than I did mine. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for this prodigious reply. It seems I do less than justice by awarding you the 'correct' answer and many thanks to Susan too. However, I still have a question. You originally took me to task for saying 'I was awoken'. Are you now saying that is possible or not? I'm not sure.

Comment: @WS2, I would say that “I was awoken” is possible, but to my ear, it sounds a bit ‘off’. Not quite ungrammatical, but ‘off’. The version that sounded quite wrong to me was, “I hope I have awoken your interest”, where we are dealing not with a passive, but a true transitive usage.

Comment: @Peter, I think that’s actually a very astute remark: with all the different forms and paradigms this cluster of verbs possesses, it’s only natural that something should be done, and suppletion is a very plausible solution. I am probably quite a bit ‘behind the times’ on this suppletion, as _I awake_ and _I have awoken_ sound much more natural to me as intransitives than _I awaken_ and _I have awakened_ do—but I would not be surprised at all if the trend were towards a single, suppletive paradigm.

Comment: @Janus I deleted my comment above so as to edit it, but you replied to it first. Here it is: Looking at Google Ngrams, one would deduce that the current usage is as a single verb with the conjugation *"I awaken", "I am awakening", "I awoke", "I have awakened"*. All of these forms are much more common than their competitors. This may be a case of suppletion caught in the act.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If ever you find yourself in Norwich, and listen to the Norfolk accent, you may well discover plenty that is 'a bit off'. Let me assure you 'I was awoken' is one of the more urbane offerings.  Normally I am aware of my Norfolkisms,but on this occasion you have drawn another of them to my attention. (I cannot precisely hit some of the Standard RP vowel sounds, even when I try. Though I have not lived in Norfolk since 1966 !)

Comment: @WS2: fwiw, the figures in Google books are *was awaken to*:378, *was awoken to*:1270, *was awakened to*:309,000. I wouldn't even bother with the history or grammatical correctness issues - just go with the vast majority on that one and ignore any criticism. Safety in numbers!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not sure I understand those. Do you mean 'was awakened' won by 309,000 to 1,270, against 'was awoken'. If so it runs counter to my instinct.

Comment: I've still got the search windows open - [was awaken to](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was+awaken+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):378 hits, [was awoken to](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was+awoken+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):1270, [was awakened to](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was+awakened+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):309,000 hits. I think your instinct must be wrong. I chose to include ***to*** to reduce the number of false positive collocations, but I didn't look past the first few results in each search to check if it worked properly.

Comment: As a result of @tchrist's housekeeping edits I have revisited this site and re-read JBJ's *opus* on the matter. In my OP I used *awake* in the active and *awaken* in the passive, whilst JBJ's preference was for *awake* intransitively and *awaken* transitively. I never at any point referred to what I might use transitively. But my inclination is to say *I wake him each morning at 7, I woke him at 8 on Thursday, and I have woken him at 7 since he was a child*. In other words for transitive use I simply miss off the first *a*.

Answer (score 1):

The words awake and awaken are two words that mean pretty much same thing.  As

[awake](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/awake): To rouse from sleep, waken; to become alert.

The simple present is I [awake](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/awake.html)

> Infinitive: to awake
>   Participle: awaked; awoken; awoke
>   Gerund: awaking
>   present passive: I am awaked/awoken/awoke.
>   simple past is: I awaked/awoke

[awaken](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/awaken) - To awake; waken; cause to become awake or conscious

> Infinitive: to awaken
>   Participle: awakened
>   Gerund: awakening
>   present passive: I am awakened.
>   simple past is: I awakened

note the difference is awaken does not take the '-woke' form

The passive voice isn't really a tense. The essential components of the English passive voice are a form of the auxiliary verb be (or sometimes get), and the *past participle* of the main verb denoting the action.

Comment: Thanks for this contribution. But I cannot say I have ever heard anyone say 'I am awaked' nor 'I am awoke'. However it was JBJ's objection to my use of 'I was awoken' which began all this.

Comment: @WS2 - I must agree with you there. I can imagine its use 2-500 years ago, though. But I can't say I ever heard it.